# Report on check in/out through sql in MS Project Server

Tags: project-server

Is check in/out status recorded in the Reporting Database in Project Server?  If so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you will find it in the reporting database by design.  However, you can look in the drafts database in [draft].[MSP_PROJECTS].  You can query where [Proj_CheckOutBy] is not null.  That will show the same list of project as you would see in "Force Check-in Enterprise Projects."

The table name may be different depending on if you are in 2010 or 2013.  Above is for 2013, but the names are pretty much the same, just all in one database instead of split into 4.